# How to calculate HSL Histogram in C#

Tags: c#, histogram, hsl

I want to calculate the histogram for an image in C# using the Hue, Saturation, Luminance values not the traditional RGB values.

Is there any way to achieve that or not?

Best regards.

Comment: Where is the problem? Loop the pixels in your image and build a dictionary with every colur-value-triple (no matter if it is HSL, RGB, CMYK or whatever you imagiine) and the ocunt of pixels with that colour.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your image to HSL color space (see, for example,  [RGB value to HSL converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472040/rgb-value-to-hsl-converter)) and then build the histogram the same way you would do it for an RGB image.